# html send get() request to Flask server every second

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I make a html page send a get() request to a server every second, so the data is updated.I have tried to use angular js for the clock/timer part, but didn't succeed. When receiving a "GET" request, the server will return a random integer to the index.html page. Javascript part sends out a GET request to the server every second. However, I couldn't see the number updated per second as I excepted.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import numpy as np
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/db', methods = ['Get'])
def hello():
    return render_template('index.html', data = np.random.randint(1,10))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

index.html

```
<html np-app='myApp'>
    <head>
        <script src="/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/myController.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body np-controller='myController'>
        {{ data }}  
    </body> 

</html>
```

myController.js

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', function getStuff($http, $timeout) {
       $http.get().success(function() {
       $timeout(getStuff, 1000);
       });
});
```

Update:
I rewrote the myController.js file, based on inf1n1te's information. But I must have done something wrong and so it didn't work:

```
myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', ['$interval', '$http', function getStuff($http, $interval) {
       $interval($http.get().success(), 1000);       
       }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

use $interval(getStuff, 1000) instead.
[angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

best way to do this is to use a websocket here.

Comment: Hey thank you, I just updated my post and I tried your method but I guess I still didn't get it right. could you look at it?